# Android giving Unknown constant tag 85 in class file

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I was working in the android studio all thing were fine until it gives me a sudden error which I have no idea how to fix it.

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Unknown constant tag 85 in class file com/android/builder/testing/ConnectedDeviceProvider
```

this bug is happening to all my projects and seams not related to my project.

Comment: I assume you tried restart and invalidate caches?

Comment: yes and I updated sdk

Comment: have you updated gradle? and what did you do so after this error comes?

Comment: After error came I try to update build tools and gradle but it did not worked

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue all I did was invalidate and restarted android studio and it was well. note I am on Android Studio Bumblebee